# SQL - Update column based on date comparasion with previous occurrence

Tags: sql, hive

I have a huge table;

[image: sample df]

I want to create a  third column based on the time difference between two dates for the same id. If the difference is less than a month, then it's active, if it is between 1-2 months then inactive and anything more than 2 is dormant. The expected outcome is below;( note last entries don't have activity definitions as I don't have previous occurrences.)

[image: expected outcome]

My question would be, how to do such operation.

`case when date_>=date_add((select max(date_) from schema.table),-30) then 'Active' when date_<date_add((select max(date_) from schema.table),-30) and date_>= date_add((select max(date_) from schema.table),-60) then 'Inactive' when  date_<date_add((select max(date_) from schema.table),-60) then 'Dormant3' end as Activity`

the code I came up with is not what I need as it only checks for the final entry date in the table. What I need is more akin to a for loop and checking the each row and comparing it to the previous occurrence.

edit:

By partitioning over id and dense ranking them, I reached something that almost works. I just need to compare to the previous element in the dense rank groups.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create base data first using LEAD()
2. Then compare than with original row.

```
SELECT ID, DATE, 
CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE,PREVIOUS_DATE) <=30 THEN 'Active'
DATEDIFF(DATE,PREVIOUS_DATE) between 31 and 60 'Active'
ELSE 'Dormant'
END as Activity
(SELECT ID, DATE, LEAD(DATE) OVER( partition by id ORDER BY DATE) PREVIOUS_DATE FROM MYTABLE) RS
```